# How can I always show my location in Google Maps

Tags: google-maps

I am using a Google Maps `iframe` in my site. "My location" pop-up is opening only on mouse click. 
I want to show the pop-up always. How can I do that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Only way I can think of is writing a JS/jQuery script that adds a .click() event to the iframe